# How to check if objects have same properties and then put a total count

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, api, object

I need some help because I'm stuck. If somebody can put me in right direction. the testArr is a much bigger file. But the simple explenation is that I need find the same period and have matching application and based on that have a total count on all payslipCount.

so if I'm searching för a period like '202103' in a date picker. I need to see total paySlipCount for that period and that application.
like

```
     period: 202103 
     pay: Pay100
     amount: total amount
```

```
testArr = [
    {application: "PAY100",
    payslipCount: 22,
    period: "202101",
    },
    
    {application: "PAY100",
    payslipCount: 12,
    period: "202101",
    },
    
    {application: "PAY600",
    payslipCount: 0,
    period: "202101",
    },
    
    {application: "PAY600",
    payslipCount: 44,
    period: "202101",
    },
    
    {application: "PAY600",
    payslipCount: 23,
    period: "202103",
    },
    
    {application: "PAY600",
    payslipCount: 44,
    period: "202103",
    },];
```

I just need somebody to push I in right direction.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: What's the actual problem? Loop over the elements, check the period, sum up the "Count"

Comment: The problem for me was to find the best way to do it and try to understund it logically and I did put lot a time to read and watch tutorials. I'm not on stack overflow to waste somebody's time. Thank you for the explanation, I was just stuck.  @Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the work. You can replace the date with a variable from the form.

```
testArr.filter(o => o.period == '202101')
       .map(item => item.payslipCount)
       .reduce((prev, next) => prev + next)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will do that! @dodododo97 Thankfull for you help!

Comment: when i try to do it with an api i get this error message " Reduce of empty array with no initial value"                                                                                                    
      let test =  this.root.filter(o => o.period == '201704' && o.application == 'PAY600')
  .map(item => item.payslipCount)
  .reduce((prev, next) => prev + next);
console.log(test); @dodododo97

Comment: So when i did it my function i got a result but when i checking outside like in the previous commnet it show me 0. Is it that i'm assning it wrong or just something else. 
`getAllRoot() {
  let test;
  this.salaryService.getAllRoot()
  .subscribe(
    (root: RootObject[]) => (this.root = root),
    (err: any) => console.log(err),
    () => {
      test = this.root.filter(o => o.period == '201612' && o.application == 'LON600')
      .map(item => item.payslipCount)
      .reduce((prev, next)=> prev + next, 0)
      console.log(test)
    }
  );
}`

@dodododo97